# Fire Nativescript tabitem event when tabitem gets selected

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I am using a Nativescript (Angular 2) TabView with two TabItems. The XML is divided intro three files. One that holds the TabView and two others for each TabItem. Therefore I also have three TypeScript components.

At the moment I am loading data in the second TabItem's onInit method. The problem is that this action already happens when the first TabItem of the TabView is being displayed/loaded.
What is the best practice to load this data only when the second TabItem is selected?

This is my (shortened) code:

home.page.html:

```
<ActionBar title="Home"></ActionBar>
<TabView #tabview (selectedIndexChanged)="tabIndexChanged($event)" toggleNavButton>

    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 1'}">
        <tab1></tab1>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 2'}">
        <tab2></tab2>
    </StackLayout>

</TabView>
```

home.page.ts:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "home-page",
    templateUrl: "./pages/home/home.page.html",
    providers: []
})

export class HomePage {

    public activeTab: string;

    public constructor() {

    }

    public tabIndexChanged(e: any) {

        switch (e.newIndex) {
            case 0:
                console.log(`Selected tab index: ${e.newIndex}`);
                break;
            case 1:
                console.log(`Selected tab index: ${e.newIndex}`);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

tab1.tab.html:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="p-20">
    <Label text="Tab 1"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

tab1.tab.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "tab1",
    templateUrl: "./pages/partials/tab1.tab.html",
    providers: []
})
export class Tab1 implements OnInit {

    public constructor() {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log("init Tab 1");
    }

}
```

tab2.tab.html:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="p-20">
    <Label text="Tab 2"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

tab2.tab.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "tab2",
    templateUrl: "./pages/partials/tab2.tab.html",
    providers: []
})
export class Tab2 implements OnInit {

    public constructor() {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log("init Tab 2");

        this.getSomeDataViaHttp();
    }

    private getSomeDataViaHttp() {
        //getting data from an API 
    }

}
```

Is there an Angular 2 / Nativescript event other than onInit that would help here?
Or should I use the method tabIndexChanged in the home.page.ts for that?
Or put all the logic and the XML for the TabView back into one xml file and one ts file?
What is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service and a Subject as followed.

1. Import the service file in all ts files (use the name and location you like):

   ```
   import { NavService } from "./services/nav.service";
   ```
2. Make sure to import it also in your app.module.ts to generally load it:

   ```
   import { NavService } from "./services/nav.service";

   @NgModule({
       declarations: [
           AppComponent,
       ],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent],
       imports: [
       ],
       providers: [
           NavService
       ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```
3. Create the service file in the specified location with the following content:

   ```
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
   import { Subject } from "rxjs";


   @Injectable()
   export class NavService {

       private currentState = new Subject<any>();

       constructor () {
       }

       setCurrentState(navPoint: number){
           this.currentState.next(navPoint);
       }


       getCurrentState() {
           return this.currentState.asObservable();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Change the tab2.tab.ts to the following:

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
   import { NavService } from "./services/nav.service";

   @Component({
       selector: "tab2",
       templateUrl: "./pages/partials/tab2.tab.html",
       providers: []
   })
   export class Tab2 implements OnInit {

           public constructor(private _navService: NavService) {}

           public ngOnInit() {
               console.log("init Tab 2");

               this._navService.getCurrentState().subscribe(
                       (state) => {
                       if (state == {{something}}) {
                           //write your code here which should be executed when state has the property {{something}}
                           this.getSomeDataViaHttp();
                       }
                       }
               );
           }

           private getSomeDataViaHttp() {
               //getting data from an API 
           }

   }
   ```
5. Call the setCurrentState of the service in your home.page.ts:

   ```
   import {Component} from "@angular/core";
   import { NavService } from "./services/nav.service";

   @Component({
       selector: "home-page",
       templateUrl: "./pages/home/home.page.html",
       providers: []
   })

   export class HomePage {

       public activeTab: string;

       public constructor(private _navService: NavService) {

       }

       public tabIndexChanged(e: any) {
           this._navService.setCurrentState(e.newIndex);

       }

   }
   ```
6. Take care that the "typeof" setting and getting the state is correct.